# Windows Server 2012 Hyper-V RDP from anywhere

Tags: windows, rdp, remote, desktop

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter installed with the Hyper-V manager activated.

Within the Hyper-V Manager I have installed two virtual machines. First virtual machine is a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard, used as a domain controller. Second virtual machine is a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard as well, used as the terminal server for remote desktop. Both are set up and have internet access.

I am able to connect to the internet and can remote to domain controller, terminal server within the network. However, outside the network, I am not able to connect. When I had a standalone Windows Server 2012 installation on a physical server without hyper-v and without virtual machines I used to install and use DynDNS.org and their DynDns updater software. Basically, I had my hostname setup with my ISP IP so I could use the hostname from anywhere and connect to the server via remote desktop. I made sure I have enabled also port forwarding for port 3389, that is all active.

I am not sure what the issue is. My best guess is a problem with the virtual switch or nat rules within Hyper-V.

Please advise me on how I can connect to the terminal server using my `hostname` e.g. `myserver.dyndns.org`.

Thanks @all

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set a static IP. The  virtual machine acts just like a physical machine on its static IP and can have a port forward setup on your router/firewall on port 3389 which will allow remote desktop connection. You also need to enable remote desktop connection in control panel > system > remote settings < allow connections from computers.

You can also follow this guide:

[Firewall and DNS/IP with Hyper V](https://ashwaniashwin.wordpress.com/2014/06/27/configure-remote-desktop-connection-to-hyper-v-virtual-machine/)

Answer (score 1):

From your post I can guess that seen from the outside your network has one public IP address, then a router, then the internal network with private IP address space (192.168.x.y, 172.x.y.z, 10.x.y.z).

You have two parts that you need to take care of - the internal network and the port forward.

**(1) Internal network.**
Set the VMs network interfaces as **bridged to the physical adapter** of the host server. In this way they will be able to directly connect to the internal (private IP) network, rather than go through a hyper-v NAT. The VMs should either have static IPs, or DHCP reservations set, so that each time the VM boots, it gets the same IP. In this way you make sure who is who.

**(2) Port forward.**
Once you know the IP address of your target host, you can set up the port forward. From your post I gather you are familiar how to do this in your router. Then test with your router's real (external) IP address first. If it works, you can set up DynDNS or other service to map hostname to your (current) IP address.

Once it works, you can either set up a single forward to access one host within your internal network, then RD to your other machines

*3389* - *192.168.1.1:3389*

or you can set up multiple port forwards to different IPs, like that:

*33891* - *192.168.1.1:3389*

*33892* - *192.168.1.2:3389*

etc.

Then you can access each server by typing

*myserver.dyndns.org:33891* to access *192.168.1.1*

*myserver.dyndns.org:33892* to access *192.168.1.2*

etc.